# Matching content between tags in web source

Tags: c#, regex, text, match

I was wondering what could be the fastest and the easiest way to grab text that is between tags in string.
For example i have this string: `Lorem ipsum <a>dolor sit amet</a>, <b>consectetur</b> adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.`
And i need to find text that is between tags `<a> </a>` and `<b> </b>`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing HTML is very very difficult, because the web pages are rarely correct and you'll find a lot of mismatched tags and strange strange things.

Use the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) if this is for real world pages.

Answer (score 1):

`<a>(.*)</a>.*<b>(.*)</b>` will work **in this particular case**, but in general it is not a good idea to parse html with regex. Use an HTML/XML parser instead.

Try [HTMLAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack): This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack) explains how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.+<a>(.+)</a>.+<b>(.+)</b>.+
```

First match group will contain the text between A-tags and second group - between B-tags.

Comment: Did you mean `()` instead of `{}`?

Comment: @Amarghosh: Yea, thanks! Mixed up with VS regex style accidentally